# How to use global variable in If condition in a Jenkinsfile?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am new to Jenkins and am confused between variables. I have tried to write a Jenkinsfile where I am simply using an If condition to deploy a file. Following is the file:

```
def checker = "Trial"

pipeline{
   agent any

   stages{
     stage('Stage 1'){
     steps{
       script{
         checker = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'echo "Trial" ')
         if (checker == 'Trial'){ echo "Hello"}
         else {echo "Hi"}
       }
     }
    }
}
}
```

The output should ideally be "Hello", however I get "Hi" always. How do I get the If condition working?? Thanks

Comment: I don't think you give a correct declartive pipeline,  miss `{}` for  `stage('Stage 1')`, miss `steps` inside `stage('Stage 1')` . How did you make your jenkins job not fail due to syntax error.

Comment: Fixed it. Actually I didn't copy the proper working snippet.

Comment: I got `Hello` printed out with filling your script in my practice pipeline job.

Comment: Yes it works with the earlier file. I added another step, and this time it doesn't work. Returns Hi always

Comment: Can you add your new step to the question, please?

Comment: @mkemmerz Already added. It's the one above the if condition.

Comment: Ah ok. Try to print your variable after the sh-command with "echo ${checker} this will display the current value of the variable. I think then it should be obvious what is happening. Probably your sh command does not return "Trial".

Comment: Just as hint: "echo" command always returns the string + a new line so It won't be equal to your 'Trial' because your command returns "Trial\n". Try to execute: "echo -n 'Trial'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed the `trim()` to remove the newline at the end of output of the bash.

`checker = sh(returnStdout: true, script: 'echo "Trial" ').trim()`